# Share video on a page on facebook

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I want to share a video from my site on a page on facebook, not on my profile.
For Eg: I want to share video on https://www.facebook.com/pages/Opticians/108277472608071

I have a button as **post to wall**. On clicking it the video should get uploaded on the above mentioned page. I searched a lot for this but I ended in getting only share button which shares the post/video to our profile. How can i share that video on a different page on facebook?

Any Help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

The reference page for this API can be found [here](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/page/videos/). And here is a [Facebook Developers blog post](https://developers.facebook.com/blog/post/493/) related to your problem.

According to this resources Facebook provides `graph-video.facebook.com` endpoint, that can be used to upload a video to user's wall. You need to perform HTTP POST request to this endpoint passing video file in `file` POST parameter.

Comment: @user2936213 This API does not work for you? What happens when you try to use it?

Comment: this is again sharing it on my wall not on a different page.

Comment: What if you try to use `graph-video.facebook.com/{page_id}/videos` endpoint to publish your video? https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/page/videos/

Comment: I am getting this error now `App Not Setup: The developers of this app have not set up this app properly for Facebook Login.`

Comment: You are getting this errors only with this endpoint? Try to publish a photo. Is it working or you get similar error?

Comment: i am getting similar error. I have created app in developers but still m not getting the page that comes for permission request

Comment: So that's another problem, unrelated to publishing video. Check your application config at developers.facebook.com. I suggest you to post another question about this problem.

Comment: Check the docs, implement example from blog post, play around with example. Links in my answer.

Comment: I tried posting video as mentioned in the link given by you. but I am unable to understand what does `video-data` mean in  `'source' => '{video-data}',` .

Comment: It's the content of your video file.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/45981/discussion-between-user2936213-and-vbo)